# I am getting a NoneType error when trying to work with Python and Sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT user_id, Class, Health, Mana, Defense, Maxmana, Maxhealth, Attack, Critical FROM savefile WHERE user_id = '{message.author.id}'")
           result1 = cursor.fetchone()
           classs = int(result1[1]); health = int(result1[2]); mana = int(result1[3]); defense = int(result1[4]); attack = int(result1[7]); critical = int(result1[8])
           sql = "UPDATE savefile SET Class = ? AND SET Health = ? AND SET Mana = ? AND SET Defense = ? AND SET Maxmana = ? AND SET Maxhealth = ? AND SET Attack = ? AND SET Critical = ? WHERE user_id = ?"
           val = (classs + classplus, str(message.author.id),
                  health + healthplus, str(message.author.id),
                  mana + manaplus, str(message.author.id),
                  defense + defenseplus, str(message.author.id),
                  attack + attackplus, str(message.author.id),
                  critical + criticalplus, str(message.author.id))
           cursor.execute(sql, val)
           db.commit()
```

This is a chunk of the code I am using. I am currently making a discord bot, and have several other commands that add to a column. However, on the "classs = ..." line, the third line in my code shown above, (extra S is on purpose) I get this error:

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'`

I am relatively new to using sqlite in general, and do not understand why this is happening. I have code similar to this in my other bot commands, and do not understand why this specifically does not work. Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of these results (result1[i]) most likely is of NoneType, meaning there is no data retrieved from the database:

```
classs = int(result1[1]); health = int(result1[2]); mana = int(result1[3]); defense = int(result1[4]); attack = int(result1[7]); critical = int(result1[8])
```

Comment: Sorry if this is kind of a newbie question, but do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: try to: `for i in result1: print(type(i))`. You will see which of the results has None value in the database. After that, you would probably want to check if the value is None before converting it to int and assign the default value. Or there is a chance that you've messed up with indexes: I see you started with result1[1], maybe you wanted result1[0] for that value?